# Base64 encoding error

Tags: php, imagemagick

the image is not showing upon clicking the upload button, base64 encoding error.

the browser is just displaying binary codes.

```
 $showimage = "images/".$_FILES['image']["name"];

$show = new imagick( $showimage );
$points = array(
            0,0, 0,0, # top left  
            213,0, 213,20, # top right
            213,160, 213,110, # bottom right 
            0,160,  0,160,# bottum left
            );
$show->setimagebackgroundcolor("#ffffff");
$show->setImageVirtualPixelMethod( imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_BACKGROUND );
$show->distortImage( Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $points, TRUE );
echo "<img src='$show'>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$imageData = base64_encode($show->getImageBlob);
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,$imageData'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `header` for the image type and also you don't have to `echo` using `<img>` tag.

Follow below code..

```
$showimage = "images/".$_FILES['image']["name"];

$show = new imagick( $showimage );
$points = array(
            0,0, 0,0, # top left  
            213,0, 213,20, # top right
            213,160, 213,110, # bottom right 
            0,160,  0,160,# bottum left
            );
$show->setimagebackgroundcolor("#ffffff");
$show->setImageVirtualPixelMethod( imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_BACKGROUND );
$show->distortImage( Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $points, TRUE );
header("Content-Type: image/png"); //<--- Provide the header
echo $show; //<--- Removed the tags

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));

// Stores image to **$imgData**  which have data ytpe blo bin mysql

```
     echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($imgData) . '"/>';
```